# What is a word that means to avoid making an admission or confession?

Tags: single-word-requests, conversation

For example:

Person A says "Stop -------ing" because Person B person was intentionally trying to steer the conversation onto other topics and avoid admitting or confessing to something unpleasant. The key here is "intentional".

If it helps, I think the word I'm looking for starts with a D and ends with "ing".

Comment: What a weird post and even stranger answers. [What do you people all _think_ railroading means](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/157561)? The correct answer would be something along the lines of _dominating_.

Comment: Of course it doesn't help that the 'clarifying' 'explanation' used the same verb again xD which was part of the problem.

Comment: to skirt the issue, to avoid the issue

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The word I was looking for is "dissembling".

Comment: In that case you were asking the wrong question. To [dissemble](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissembling) means to *conceal one's true motives, feelings, or beliefs*. That's not at all the same thing as *railroading* a conversation. Which actually means to forcibly steer it in a certain direction and not allow others to change the topic, whereas I admit my *digressing* usually implies unfocussed straying from the primary topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah... This was so far out of left field and NONE of the answers (including yours somehow) had anything to do with the idea of railroading at all. I rephrased the entire thing from the ground up to get it closer to the intent. Look it over and fine tune it if you think I got it a little off.

Answer (score 10):

You're probably looking for [digress](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/digress), *to deviate or wander away from the main topic or purpose in speaking or writing; depart from the principal line of argument, plot, study, etc.*

There are various other words with much the same meaning - *meander, wander, deviate, sidetrack, ramble,* etc., but none are so tightly associated with discourse (particularly in speech).

Comment: Close!! The word I was actually looking for was "dissembling". But my example wasn't quite right.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sharon: Digress is actually a much better fit than dissemble. You might check the definitions and some example usages.

Comment: After further discussion on Meta, I'm removing this post as accepted since it doesn't match the current description of the question, and only partially matched though original, though this was the answer that was most helpful in getting to the actual solution, which is "dissembling".

Answer (score 6):

One option is [*deviating*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deviating):

> **v. de·vi·at·ed, de·vi·at·ing, de·vi·ates**
>
> *v.intr.*
>
> 1. To turn aside from a course or way.
> 2. To depart, as from a norm, purpose, or subject; stray. See Synonyms at swerve.
>
> *v.tr.*
>
> To cause to turn aside or differ.

Another option, to continue your metaphor of railroading a conversation, is [*derailing*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/derailing):

> *intr. & tr.v*. **de·railed, de·rail·ing, de·rails**
>
> 1. To run or cause to run off the rails.
> 2. To come or bring to a sudden halt:

Answer (score 5):

A term commonly used is "side-tracking" :

> Stop sidetracking!