# Formal expression for "talking about something unrelated"

Tags: phrase-requests, formality

What are some words or phrases that can be used when a person is discussing a particular subject with a group of people and unintentionally she/he talks about something unrelated? I need a formal expression.

Comment: The usual expression is 'beside the point', but if someone is being evasive we might complain that they're 'going off the point'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a word that means "to railroad the conversation"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36853/what-is-a-word-that-means-to-railroad-the-conversation)

Comment: *going down a rabbit trail*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are a few ways of expressing that, from casual to more formal:

- Going off-topic
- Getting off track
- Rambling or not getting to the point
- Losing focus
- Digressing
- Tangential to the discussion
- Not relevant to the topic at hand
- Diverting the conversation
- Subject is not pertinent to the conversation

Comment: These are exactly what I have been looking for!! Thanks!!

Comment: Great! I'm happy I was able to help!

Comment: One might also say "on a side note..." or related to "tangential to the discussion" but less formal "(going) off on a tangent"

Answer (score 2):

The expression you need is *"That's beside the point*". Alternatively you can also say *"That's irrelevant*."

Answer (score 2):

I'm fond of going *off-topic*.  You could also say that they are *going off on a tangent* or *speaking tangentially*.

Comment: "Fond of going *off-topic*." - good you don't ask many questions here then :P

Comment: Speaking of good burger joints...

Comment: I saw a turtle!

Comment: @cornbreadninja Oooo shiny! But that isn't formal ;o) I liked the turtle.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: "digress". It means to go off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Funny no one has mentioned this yet. I thought I might as well include this. It's ["sidetrack"](http://www.answers.com/topic/sidetrack)   :

> To divert from a main issue or course: