# What to say when someone's answer is not related to our question or at least we think it's not?

Tags: idioms, slang, phrasal-verbs, business-language, conversation

I would say: "How's that related to my question ?"
Please answer for both formal and informal cases

Comment: Is it relevant that the first utterance should be a ***question***, and the second an ***answer*** (albeit not "recognised" as an answer by the first speaker)? I'm specifically asking that because a ***non-sequitur*** doesn't normally have any implications of "not an answer to the question just asked" - it just means "not meaningfully connected to preceding utterances" (usually, within the context of a *conversation*, not an *interrogation*).

Comment: (1) Non/germane / Off-topic / Going off at a tangent / Digress / a non-sequitur (2) Sidetrack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formal expression for "talking about something unrelated"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62368/formal-expression-for-talking-about-something-unrelated) (one answer has a list graded from informal to formal).

Comment: The usual answer when that happens is "Why do you say that?"

Comment: Also [***What do you call a response which does not address the question?***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215722/what-do-you-call-a-response-which-does-not-address-the-question/215730) - which going by the title should be a pretty good match!