# Is there a word or fixed phrase / idiom for a vicious circle of obtuseness?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests

I recently told my father-in-law that I thought he was being obtuse, and he then acted as if he didn’t understand the concept of being obtuse. I feel like there’s a word for this. What would we call such a situation as this?

Comment: Perhaps his confusion was occasioned by his always thinking of you as obtuse. Now that really would be circular.

Comment: Related: [What is a word that means 'to railroad the conversation'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36853/what-is-a-word-that-means-to-railroad-the-conversation/37368#37368) (The duplicate has answers including _playing dumb, 
feigning ignorance, 
being deliberately obtuse; disingenuous ..._).

Comment: Yes...Lt. Columbo was accused several times of "being _deliberately_ obtuse".

Answer (score 2):

OED:

**dissemble**, v.1 1. transitive. **To alter or disguise the semblance of (one's character, a feeling, design, or action) so as to conceal, or deceive as to, its real nature; to give a false or feigned semblance to; to cloak or disguise by a feigned appearance.**

a1535   T. More Hist. Richard III in Wks. (1557) 65/1   *Some..not able to dissemble theyr sorow, were faine at his backe to turne their face to the wall.*

1709   Tatler No. 32. ⁋4   *With an Air of great Distance, mixed with a certain Indifference, by which he could dissemble Dissimulation.*

MW

**dissemble**

*transitive verb*

**1 : to hide under a false appearance dissembling the facts**
**2 : to put on the appearance of : simulate** *She lay down and dissembled sleep.*

*intransitive verb*

: **to put on a false appearance : conceal facts, intentions, or feelings under some pretense** *He had dissembled about the risks involved.*